# Office.js Outlook add-in InternetHeaders Prefer ImmutableId

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in (React with a dotnet core backend). I want to take advantage of the immutable ID for mail messages. [This page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/blogs/announcing-immutable-id-for-outlook-resources-in-microsoft-graph/) says

> UPDATE (Jan 15, 2019): This feature is now available in **Microsoft Graph v1.0** and beta as an “opt-in”. Graph will continue to return regular IDs by default.

So in order to access this feature I need to send an HTTP header in API requests:

```
Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"
```

There is an API that does this:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.setAsync({"Prefer": "IdType=\"ImmutableId\""});
```

In the React component for composing a message, the request succeeds in the `componentDidMount()` method but doesn't generate an ImmutableId [Edited - the [`setAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview#setasync-headers--callback-) method is only available for composing a message]. In the process of writing the question I found an answer on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/update-your-javascript-api-for-office-and-manifest-schema-version):

> You'll need to take a few additional steps to complete the update. In the head tag of your add-in's HTML pages, comment out or delete any existing office.js script references, and reference the updated JavaScript API for Office library as follows:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> The /1/ in the office.js in the CDN URL specifies to use the latest incremental release within version 1 of Office.js.

I've updated the `taskpane.html` file with the updated script reference but the request is still failing - the id's are never immutable, even when the header is set successfully, the itemId is just the standard volatile id that changes when the item is moved between folders. Is there a sample that demonstrates the successful use of this functionality?

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders is for working with email MIME headers. It is not related to the REST ImmutableId header.  Currently Outlook add-ins do not support immutable id.  What's your scenario?  Are you primarily interested in getting immutable ID's for items through Outlook addins?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get an immutable id for a mail item for an Outlook add-in.

Answer (score 0):

The first doc describes an HTML header to set when making calls to a Microsoft Graph or  Exchange REST API. This may be important for you later depending on how you use the id.

To get the immutable id for an Outlook item:

1. Get the EWS item id from `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`
2. Make a remote service call to the [`translateExchangeIds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id#updating-existing-data) REST API to exchange the REST id for an immutable ID

This is an incomplete example of how to call the REST API from an Outlook add-in. It's missing an access token because the `translateExchangeIds` REST API requires `User.ReadBasic` permissions, which isn't a scope of the token returned by the getClientAccessToken API. This abbreviated example is based on the [making REST API calls from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) article, which contains more information about making other requests like this one.

```
var accessToken = "" // Need access token with User.ReadBasic or greater permissions
var itemIdFormat = "ewsId";

var translateExchangeIdsUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl +
    '/v2.0/me/translateExchangeIds/';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: translateExchangeIdsUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        InputIds : [
            Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId
        ],
        "SourceIdType": itemIdFormat,
        "TargetIdType": "restImmutableEntryId"
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
}).done(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

You also can create a feature request for a client-side immutable id API on the Outlook add-ins [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778). Feature requests on UserVoice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: For anyone wanting to update this idea, I've created a request here on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39183742-get-immutable-id-s-from-office-js-context