# Trying to get immutable ids via v2.0 REST API

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I working on an outlook addin ( currently testing in the web ) I need to get some immutable ids so that i can store references to these emails on our platform.  I read this [great response by the Outlook team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228796/office-js-outlook-add-in-internetheaders-prefer-immutableid) and have been trying all day to call translateExchangeIds with no success. First off I really couldn't find a doc stating that this endpoint actually existed on the REST v2.0 API.  I can kind of tell it does exist because I get error messages saying that the payload doesn't match what the endpoint says it needs if i just change the capitalization of the json object a little bit.  I'm currently getting an error

```
code: "ErrorAccessDenied" message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
```

That seems pretty obvious what I should be doing is checking my permissions.  The docs I can find mention that I need User.ReadBasic.  This really isn't how I would define permissions for an outlook addin though.  In the manifest.xml file for my adding I have defined permissions

```
 <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
```

This should be more than enough to call this endpoint

```js
const getImmutableId = async () => new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(
    { isRest: true },
    (result: Office.AsyncResult<string>) => {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${result.value}`);
      headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('data-type', 'json');
      headers.append('process-data', 'false');
      fetch(`${Office.context.mailbox.restUrl}/v2.0/me/translateExchangeIds`, {
        headers,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          InputIds: [
            Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
          ],
          SourceIdType: 'ewsId',
          TargetIdType: 'restImmutableEntryId',
        }),
      }).then((response: Response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then((restResponse: {targetId: string, sourceId: string}[]) => {
            resolve(restResponse[0].targetId);
          });
        } else {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.warn('there was a failire to get an immutable id falling back to mutable rest id');
          resolve(Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
            Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0,
          ));
        }
      });
    },
  );
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The StackOverflow post that you read ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228796/office-js-outlook-add-in-internetheaders-prefer-immutableid)) states that the sample code is incomplete because the token provided by the [`getAccessTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) API call is missing the [`User.ReadBasic.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) permission which is required by the [`translateExchangeIds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) REST API. There is an existing [UserVoice post](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39183742-get-immutable-id-s-from-office-js-context) regarding Immutable IDs. Please add your voice there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: so getAccessTokenAsync is only available in the preview version of the Office js library correct?  getCallbackTokenAsync <-- will not work for getting me the token i need to make this call?  I don't understand where User.ReadBasic.All is coming from. It's not an option that I see available for the Permission element in the manifest.xml https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission  What about a property like InternetMessageId?  I won't be able to look up a message using this but it's unique and un-changing?

Comment: Yes, getAccessTokenAsync is in preview, per our documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=outlook-js-preview. The token obtained from getCallbackTokenAsync does not contain the User.ReadBasic.All permission. User.ReadBasic.All (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions) is a permission for Graph APIs that will need to be embedded in the token to allow you successfully call translateExchangeIds. This permission is separate from the one in your add-in's manifest xml file.

Comment: Internet message IDs are meant to be unique, however, they are optional and dependent on the server that created them. Since your e-mail account can receive e-mails from multiple sources, the internet message IDs may not be reliably unique per mailbox. More information here : http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html